# Table column fixed size is not giving the desired result, why not?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

At the moment I'm only designing a page as a proof of concept and I'm trying to set the first item of a table to a fixed size (100px). But the column is almost never exactly 100px, sometimes it's 101px, at other times it's more, sometimes even less. The times I get the width to be exactly 100px there are problems with the table as a whole (width != 100%)

The table layout is mainly provided by bootstrap css, but for the width (and image sizes) I have written a bit of css myself. I'm not 100% sure this was necessary.

Below the html and css (not bootstrap) with which I'm trying to create this.

HTML:

```
<table class="table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive table-bordered conexio-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Foto</th>
            <th>Naam</th>
            <th>Adres</th>
            <th>E-mailadres</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- Contact -->
        <tr>
            <td class="conexio-table-img">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Icons/Contacts.png" alt="Information contact" />
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Icons/Error.png" alt="Information Error" />
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Icons/Conflicts.png" alt="Information conflicts" /><br />
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Icons/Doubtfuls.png" alt="Information doubtful" />
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Icons/Duplicates.png" alt="Information duplicates" />
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Icons/Duplicates.png" alt="Information duplicates" />
            </td>
            <td class="conexio-table-img">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Images/Temp/photo.jpg" alt="Profile picture" />
            </td>
            <td>Bobby Hippo</td>
            <td>companystreet 123, 9999 worktown</td>
            <td>bob@b-bob.hippopotamus</td>
        </tr> 
        <!-- Contact -->
        <tr>
            <td class="conexio-table-img">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Icons/Contacts.png" alt="Information contact" />
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Icons/Error.png" alt="Information error" />
            </td>
            <td class="conexio-table-img">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Images/empty_profile.jpg" alt="Profile picture" />
            </td>
            <td>Gerry Giraffe</td>
            <td>2260 Westerlo, Antwerpen, België</td>
            <td>gerry@g-gerry.giraffe</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.conexio-table {
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
}

.conexio-table th:first-child td:first-child {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.conexio-table td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.conexio-table-img img {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
 }
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle with your code on http://www.bootply.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you just can add `<col width="100px">`. As seen on the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/t2fagera/

Comment: I have moved the col tag in a colgroup because ReSharper was giving errors. I have also put the width in a class in css and assigned that class to the col